# BASHOPTS not populated

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using the bash shell on MacOS. It appears that `BASHOPTS` isn't populated; `echo $BASHOPTS` outputs nothing. Is this expected?

This isn't the behavior on Linux instances I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `BASHOPTS` in the default bash included with macOS. [The variable BASHOPTS was introduced with bash 4.1.](https://www.techpaste.com/2012/12/bashopts-bash-linux/) The macOS operating system on Intel Macs with macOS Big Sur 11.4 only has bash up to the following.

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
```

I assume the M1 Macs offer nothing significantly newer. I heard this is basically a licensing issue causing the version to be this old. I believe you can manually upgrade to a newer version of bash if you wish.

Comment: Newer versions can be installed via Homebrew.

Comment: Thanks for finding this. Rather curious what licensing issue could be, as bash is under GPLv3. Have they made modifications to it to work better with MacOS? If so, will brew's newer version capture those modifications?

Comment: From my understanding, if macOS was released with a newer version of bash, then Apple would be obligated to allow macOS to be installed on hardware made by other manufacturers. Which is under GPLv3. This is why, macOS now uses zsh as the default shell. There is no physical (including software) reason newer versions of bash can not be installed on Macs running macOS. Just for legal reasons the user needs to do this themselves by using Homebrew or some other means. I do not know of any modifications made to make bash work better with MacOS.